# Works while opening but crashes upon reload

Tags: javascript

So I try to create three values between 1 and 3 that are going to be different every time the page loads. It works perfectly when I open the page the first time, but whenever I try to reload or submit my form the page freeze and it is stuck loading. Any help is much appreciated!

```
function uniqueAnswerId(){
    var rand = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    while (Math.round(rand) == 0) {
        var rand = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    }
    return (Math.round(rand));
}
var answerId1 = uniqueAnswerId();

function uniqueAnswerId2(){
    var rand2 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    while (answerId1 == Math.round(rand2) || Math.round(rand2) == 0) {
        var rand2 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    }
    return (Math.round(rand2));
}

var answerId2 = uniqueAnswerId2();

function uniqueAnswerId3(){
    var rand3 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    while (answerId1 == Math.round(rand3) || answerId2 == Math.round(rand3)){
        while (Math.round(rand3) == 0){
            var rand3 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
        }
    }
    return (Math.round(rand3));
}

var answerId3 = uniqueAnswerId3();

console.log("AnswerIds: " + (answerId1) + ", " + (answerId2) + ", " + (answerId3))
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: I ran an error check in console and when I try to add a third "||" condition I get an error on that. But changing == to === did the trick! Too familiar with swift unfortunately, so its a struggle to go back to javascript.. Thank you so much for all the answers! Its been great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 3rd while loop should look like this, with another "||" in your condition instead of a whole new while loop.

```
function uniqueAnswerId3(answerId1, answerId2){
    var rand3 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    while (answerId1 === Math.round(rand3) || answerId2 === Math.round(rand3) || Math.round(rand3)===0){
             rand3 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    }
    return (Math.round(rand3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an infinite loop. Here is the fiddle to fix your code.

Changes: Use '===' instead of '=='

Function Hoisting executes those functions before the variable declarations, which means referencing them inside the functions doesn't work. Added parameters to accept the arguments required.

https://jsfiddle.net/80xdmsjL/

```
function uniqueAnswerId(){
    var rand = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    while (Math.round(rand) === 0) {
        rand = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    }
    return (Math.round(rand));
}

var answerId1 = uniqueAnswerId();

function uniqueAnswerId2(answerId1){
    var rand2 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    while (answerId1 === Math.round(rand2) || Math.round(rand2) === 0) {
         rand2 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    }
    return (Math.round(rand2));
}

var answerId2 = uniqueAnswerId2(answerId1);

function uniqueAnswerId3(answerId1, answerId2){
    var rand3 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
    while (answerId1 === Math.round(rand3) || answerId2 === Math.round(rand3)){
        while (Math.round(rand3) === 0){
             rand3 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
        }
    }
    return (Math.round(rand3));
}

var answerId3 = uniqueAnswerId3(answerId1, answerId2);

console.log("AnswerIds: " + (answerId1) + ", " + (answerId2) + ", " + (answerId3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this part of your code:

```
while (answerId1 === Math.round(rand3) || answerId2 === Math.round(rand3)){
        while (Math.round(rand3) === 0){
             rand3 = (Math.random() * 3.4);
        }
    }
```

Lets see what happen with the following values:

- answerId1 = 1
- answerId1 = 2
- Math.round(rand3) = 1

in this case, you will have:

```
while (true){
    while(false){
        never_executed();
    }
}
```

So it will loop until infinite in the outer 'while'.

To avoid this you could simply do what @Nicholas Bakolias says, add 'another "||" in your condition instead of a whole new while loop'